# Map prop data outside render method in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I want to map data outside render method in the function and return it in render. But I am getting mapping error, I am not sure about the cause.

Below is the function which should map the data outside render:

```
filterItems = (itemList) => {
        let result = [];

        const { searchInput,alphabet } = this.state;
        if(searchInput || alphabet) {
          result = itemList.filter((element) => (element.name.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === alphabet.toLowerCase()) && 
          this.elementContainsSearchString(searchInput, element));
        } else {
          result = itemList;
        }    
        result = result.map((item)=> (<li>{item.name}<a href="#"><img src={item.image_url} className="img-responsive" /></a></li>))
        return result;
      }
```

Accessing like this in render method:

```
let celebrity = this.props.items.celebrity
const filteredList = this.filterItems(celebrity);
return (
        <div className="container no-padding">
            <div className="row celeb-grid">
                <ul className="no-padding celeb-items col-md-12">
                    {filteredList}

                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
```

Note: I am getting the data if I do console.log:

```
console.log (celebrity);
```

Error Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can see the `celebrity` contents you say. But is it an array ? Do a `console.log` from inside the `filterItems` method. Or better yet debug it step by step

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please try to use the official Stack Overflow image CDN at `i.stack.imgur.com`. We find that other CDNs often let old images expire, which will give volunteers some clean-up work at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're fetching a celebrity list from an endpoint, perhaps in `componentDidMount`, but you're rendering the component before that data has loaded. That means you're passing in `undefined` to the `filterItems` method and, regardless of the outcome of the condition, result will be `undefined`, and you can't `map` over something that's undefined.

To solve this you need your component to display something other than the list before the data has loaded.

```
let { celebrity } = this.props.items;

if (!celebrity && !celebrity.length) return <div />

return (
  <div className="container no-padding">
    <div className="row celeb-grid">
      <ul className="no-padding celeb-items col-md-12">
        {this.filterItems(celebrity)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```